# Failing on Bag.to_avro becase of Killed/MemoryError on a large dataset

Tags: dask

I am trying to process a large set of text files which are delimitated by new lines. The files are gzipped and I've split the files into small chunks where uncompressed they are ~100mb or so. I have a total of 296 individual compressed files with a total uncompressed size of ~30Gb.

The rows are [NQuads](https://www.w3.org/TR/n-quads/) and I'm using a `Bag` to map the rows into a format which I can import into a database. The rows are being folded by key so that I can combine rows related to a single page.

This is the code I'm using to read the files and fold them.

```
with dask.config.set(num_workers=2):
  n_quads_bag = dask.bag.\
    read_text(files)

  uri_nquads_bag = n_quads_bag.\
    map(parser.parse).\
    filter(lambda x: x is not None).\
    map(nquad_tuple_to_page_dict).\
    foldby('uri', binop=binop).\
    pluck(1).\
    map(lang_extract)
```

Then I'm normalizing the data into pages and entities. I'm doing this by a map function which splits things into a tuple with `(page, entities)`. I am plucking the data and then writing it to two separate sets of files in Avro.

```
  pages_entities_bag = uri_nquads_bag.\
      map(map_page_entities)

  pages_bag = pages_entities_bag.\
    pluck(0).\
    map(page_extractor).\
    map(extract_uri_details).\
    map(ntriples_to_dict)

  entities_bag = pages_entities_bag.\
    pluck(1) .\
    flatten().\
    map(entity_extractor).\
    map(ntriples_to_dict)

  with ProgressBar():
    pages_bag.to_avro(
      os.path.join(output_folder, 'pages.*.avro'),
      schema=page_avro_scheme,
      codec='snappy',
      compute=True)
    entities_bag.to_avro(
      os.path.join(output_folder, 'entities.*.avro'),
      schema=entities_avro_schema,
      codec='snappy',
      compute=True)
```

The code is failing on `pages_bag.to_avro(... compute=True)` with `Killed/MemoryError`. I've played around with reducing the partition sizes and reduced the processor count to 2.

Am I wrong in setting `compute=True`? Is this the reason that the whole dataset is being brought into memory?  If so how else can I get the files to be written?

Or is it possible that the partitions of the pages or entities are way too big for the computer?

Another question I had is am I using the `Bags` incorrectly and is this the right approach for the problem I want to solve?

The specs of the Machine I'm running this on:

- 4 CPU
- 16GB of Ram
- 375 Scratch Disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get this to not run out of memory is to keep the files ~100MB uncompressed and to use a `groupby`. As the Dask documentation states you can force it shuffle on disk. The `groupby` supports setting a number of partitions on the output.

```
with dask.config.set(num_workers=2):
  n_quads_bag = dask.bag.\
    read_text(files)

  uri_nquads_bag = n_quads_bag.\
    map(parser.parse).\
    filter(lambda x: x is not None).\
    map(nquad_tuple_to_page_dict).\
    groupby(lambda x: x[3], shuffle='disk', npartitions=n_quads_bag.npartitions).\        
    map(grouped_nquads_to_dict).\
    map(lang_extract)
```